# Why PHP doesn't receive values from my select?

Tags: php, html

> Notice: Undefined index: perm_tipo in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_reg_usuario.php on line 6

I get this error from my PHP page where is supposed to receive a value from a 
html select form, I send this info with POST, this is the code from my select:

```
<select name="perm_tipo">
            <?php
                 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
                  mysql_select_db("test",$con) or die(mysql_error());              
                  $sql = "SELECT id_permiso,tipo_permiso FROM cat_permisos";              
                  $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ 
                   echo "<option value='".$row["id_permiso"]."'>".$row["tipo_permiso"]."</option>";            
                }
                mysql_free_result($rs); 

               mysql_close($con);
                ?>
            </select>
```

and another php page to use the values I use this

```
$permiso = $_POST['perm_tipo'];
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, the syntax and name are fine.

EDIT: now is working,the var_dump($_POST); code made it work??, =S

Comment: Can you post your <form ...> declaration please?

Comment: in your file admin_reg_usario.php, do a `var_dump($_POST);` and see if your post variable 'perm_tipo' is actually present.

Comment: check for ur method in form.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you have "tipo_permiso" in  your form and check for "perm_tipo".

Comment: @Mir the whole form is pretty big so going to  only put this:

<form action="admin_reg_usuario.php" method="post">

Comment: @McKracken tipo_permiso comes from the Database

Comment: @McKracken - looks to me like the select's name is perm_tipo, so yes, he does.

Comment: As an aside: Stop using *MySQL* it is deprecated. Use ***MySQLi*** or ***PDO*** instead . Small changes. Big impact. :-) . Standard mysql is not maintained, patched, updated, and has known security weaknesses. The new standard is MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @Martin good suggestion but that's not the answer :)

Comment: that's why it's in a comment :-p @Tek

Comment: In answer to the question - the phrase *"perm_tipo"* does not appear anywhere in the code you've displayed except that referenced as "another page". Please show us line 6 of the page that causes the error on PHP error log.

Comment: You need to show how your form works, you form is probably posting the data as a GET request rather than a POST.

Comment: @Martin "perm_tipo" is the name of the select

Comment: yes but perm_tipo is not in the PHP code block that the OP is showing, but the error in the error log at the top is a PHP error, which means the error appears upon searching for a *$_SOMETHING['perm_tipo']* on line 6. There's some missing information there. @Rickkwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you're submitting the form to the same PHP page.

That means when you first visit the page, `$_POST` is empty. After you click submit `$_POST` is populated when the form is sent to the same page with `perm_tipo`.

What you need to make sure is that `$_POST` is sent to your PHP page with `isset`. This will detect when your form is submitted. This will also not execute the code when `$_POST` is empty which is why you get that "Notice:" error.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['perm_tipo']))
{
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("test",$con) or die(mysql_error());              
    $sql = "SELECT id_permiso,tipo_permiso FROM cat_permisos";              
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ 
        echo "<option value='".$row["id_permiso"]."'>".$row["tipo_permiso"]."</option>";            
    }
    mysql_free_result($rs); 

    mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```